# How to express an Alphabet Loop in pseudocode (within the context of a Caesar Cipher)?

Tags: pseudocode, encryption

I'm presented with supplying pseudocode to represent the logic behind expressing a Caesar Cipher. I've done a decent job of conceptualizing my variables and the steps needed to accomplish this but I can't think of how to express the looping of the alphabet. More specifically say we are using a shift of 5, if the input plaintext character is an x... how do I go about representing the loop back to the beginning of the alphabet? I feel like I'm having a hard time on an incredibly simple idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
function shiftChar(plainChar, shift)
  temp <- plainChar + shift
  if (temp > z)
  then
    temp <- temp - z
  else if (temp < a) // For negative shifts
    temp <- temp + z
  endif
  return temp
end shiftChar
```

Was that really so difficult?